# Edit pages in Elementor from WP Admin Bar

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages, wp-admin

I need a way of quickly getting to edit in elementor from Wordpress admin without having to return to the pages page. There are probably plugins but I need a quick solutions made in wordpress that I can implement without having to install a bulky plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to /wp-includes and find the class-wp-admin-bar.php.
2. Scroll down to the id="wpadminbar" section

[image: WordPress WP-Admin Menu HTML]

3. This code will pull pages, replace links for Elementor and style the menu. Insert this after...

   ```
        <!-- Calls the Wordpress Menu -->
        <ul class="edit-pages-menu">
            <?php wp_list_pages();?>

        </ul>
        <!-- Adds the appropriate classes and elementor parameters -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery('.edit-pages-menu  .pagenav').prepend('Edit ').append(' in Elementor');
            jQuery('.edit-pages-menu > li').addClass('menupop');
            jQuery('.edit-pages-menu .pagenav > ul').wrap('<div class="ab-sub-wrapper"></div>').addClass('ab-submenu');
            jQuery('.edit-pages-menu a').each(function(){
                    jQuery(this).addClass('ab-item');
                }
            );
            jQuery('.edit-pages-menu .ab-submenu li').each(function(){
                    var link = jQuery(this).attr('class');
                    var pageID = link.substr(link.length - 2);
                   jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href', '/wp-admin/post.php?post='+pageID+'&action=elementor').attr('target','_blank');
                }
            ); 
        </script>
        <!--  Style Menu To Wordpress -->
        <style >
            ul.edit-pages-menu li.pagenav.menupop {
                display: block!important;
                padding-left: 10px!important;
                padding-right: 10px!important;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            ul.edit-pages-menu {
                display: block;
                float: left;

            }
            ul.edit-pages-menu ul.ab-submenu {
                padding: 0;
                display: block!important;
                float: left!important;
                width: 160px!important;
            }
            ul.ab-submenu, ul.ab-submenu li {
                padding: 0;
                display: block!important;
                float: left!important;
                width:100%!important;

            }
            ul.edit-pages-menu a {
                padding-left: 10px!important;
                padding-right: 10px!important;
                display: block!important;
                float:left!important;
            }
            ul.edit-pages-menu a:hover {
                color:#72aee6!important;
            }
        </style>
   ```
4. Result is something like this, that when clicked will take you directly to edit in elementor in new tab.

[image: Edit In Elementor Menu]

5. Change the parameters in the href for any plugin you prefer.